# Syntax Error on '='

Tags: syntax-error, verilog

I have the following Verilog HDL code. It is basically a two-bit adder that adds `a` and `b`, and has a PG unit, Carry-generate unit (`cg_unit`), and Sum unit (`s_unit`). The `ci` is the carry-in for the two-bit adder. `sel` is what activates the trojan, i.e. negates the value of `s[1]`. `coutminus1` and `cout` are simply the carry-out and the carry previous to the carryout, respectively.

```
module trojan
(
  input [1:0] a, b,
  input ci, sel,
  output [1:0] s,
  output cout, coutminus1
);

  wire [1:0] c, p, g;
  cla_pg_unit_2bits       pgu1(a, b, p, g);
  cla_cg_unit_2bits       cgu1(p, g, ci, c);
  cla_s_unit_2bits        su1(p, {c[0], ci}, s);
  coutminus1 = c[0];
  cout = c[1];

  always@(sel)
  begin
    if (sel == 1)
      assign s[1] = ~s[1];
    else
      assign s[1] = s[1];
  end
endmodule
```

For some reason I get the following syntax error:

```
Following Verilog source has the following syntax error: token is '=' 
coutminus1 = c[0];
           ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this lines:

```
coutminus1 = c[0];
cout = c[1];
```

the keyword `assign` is missing. There are also some other issues with your code. I'd propose to change it to something like this:

```
module trojan
(
  input [1:0] a, b,
  input ci, sel,
  output [1:0] s,
  output cout, coutminus1
);

wire [1:0] c, p, g, tmp;

cla_pg_unit_2bits       pgu1(a, b, p, g);
cla_cg_unit_2bits       cgu1(p, g, ci, c);
cla_s_unit_2bits        su1(p, {c[0], ci}, tmp);

assign coutminus1 = c[0];
assign cout = c[1];
assign s = {(sel) ? ~tmp[1] : tmp[1], tmp[0]};

endmodule
```

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me four new errors. One is: `illegal behavior of left-hand side. Bit select or part select cannot be used on the left-hand side of this assignment. The offending expression is : s[1]` `assign s[1] = (~s[1]);`

Comment: I need the `s` to be an output because it is used in another module. How do I go about this situation? Also, I thought that the `assign` keyword was necessary when boolean algebra is in the expression. Is this not true?

Comment: I get the following error when declaring `s` as an `output reg`: `Register 's' is illegally connected to output port "s" of module 
  "cla_s_unit_2bits", instance "su1".`

Comment: @thetypist: please take a look at code that I proposed.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. However, why wouldn't my `always` block in my original post work as well, assuming I used tmp as well?

Comment: Got it, had to declare my `s` as an `output reg`, as you suggested earlier.

Comment: @thetypist also note that the assign inside an always block means something different than an assign outside. An assign outside an always block serves to connect nets/variables to other nets/variables (like in the code above). An assign inside an always block acts like a force, which is typically not the desired behavior. Just use equals (`=` or `<=` depending on type of hardware being inferred) in always blocks, without the assign keyword.